# How to compile .war that includes source attachment using ANT

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ant, war

So I am using Apache Tomcat to deploy the .war file that I generate using ANT in Eclipse.
When debugging using the source code of Tomcat in Eclipse, I always get the no source attachment display.

I need the **.class** and the **.java** to connect to each other in order for me to be able to debug.

My javac task looks like this

```
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${tmp}/WEB-INF/classes" source="1.6" target="1.6">
          <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${lib2}">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
</javac>
```

suggestions would be appreciated.

I am debugging Tomcat on eclipse using those arguments

> catalina jpda start